# How does atmospherejs.com create the transition in and out of the search page?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I want to be create a fullscreen search page that is opened and closed via sessions. But I don't want to just have a blank screen pop out of nowhere; I want something similar to what atmospherejs.com does when you start searching. Here is what I have so far:

The fullscreen search page

```
 <template name="searchPage">
     <div class="container">
          <input id="search">
     </div>
 </template
```

The home page

```
 <template name="homePage">
     <div class="content">
        // everything else on the home page...
     </div>

     {{#if searchIsOpen}}
     {{> searchPage}}
     {{/if}}
 </template
```

Opening the search page

```
 Template.homePage.events({
     'click #open-button: function (e) {
          Session.set('openSearch', 'true');
     }
 });
```

Closing the search page

```
 Template.searchPage.events({
     'click #close-button: function (e) {
          Session.set('openSearch', null');
     }
 });
```

Controlling the session

```
 Template.homePage.helpers({
     searchIsOpen: function (e) {
          Session.get('openSearch');
     }
 });
```

I'm not sure if I need a certain package, or how I can combine opening with sessions while also using a transition animation. Ultimately I want the home page's content to fade out when the search page fades in, and vice-versa. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atmosphere transitions the search page via CSS by setting the equivalent of an '.show-search' class on the layout container and always rendering an empty search page (hidden).

Not interested in the CSS-centric technique? Checkout [percolate:momentum](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/momentum) which leverages Meteor's UI-hooks to animate nodes in/out without flashing screens.